# Doomfist Rocket Punch vs Reinhardt Charge

Tags: overwatch

Which would win out of Doomfist and Reinhardt for Rocket Punch vs Charge? Does it matter who starts? Also what significance is the casting time of Rocket Punch?

Answer (score 7):

Just like two Reinhardt charging at each other, when a Reinhardt and a Doomfist clash they will both be knocked down and take no damage.